# How can I get values from multiples inputs by the name attribute?

Tags: jquery

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="Preco0" name="produtosBonificacao[0].Preco" value="" placeholder="Preço Sistema" readonly="readonly">

<input type="text" class="form-control" id="Preco1" name="produtosBonificacao[1].Preco" value="" placeholder="Preço Sistema" readonly="readonly">
```

I have to get these values and to sum all of them...

```
function subotal() {
    var sum = 0.0;
    $('input[name^="produtosBonificacao[].Preco"]').each(function () {
        var price = $(this).val();
        sum += price;
    });
    //I need to set the sum in readonly input. 

}
```

After that, I need to set the total of the sum at somewhere.

Comment: Can you give us an idea of what your current result is along with what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please look into below example, might be helpful [please refer comment for explanation]

```
function subotal() {
   var sum = 0.0;
   //1. get input elements whose name starts with "produtosBonificacao"
   $('input[name^="produtosBonificacao"]').each(function () {
        //2. Make sure that input belongs to "Preco" property
        if($(this).attr('name').indexOf('.Preco')>-1)
        {
           //3. Parse value, for this example just use parseInt
           //Make sure that you don't need parseFloat.
           //Before using parsed value into sum, just make sure that it is valid number.
           var price = parseInt($(this).val());
           sum += (isNaN(price)?0: price);
        }
    });
    //I need to set the sum in readonly input. 
    alert(sum);
}
$(document).ready(function(){
subotal();

})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vrluckyin/4j71uc93/11/

Comment: I got it.  Thx for your help. =)

Answer (score 0):

The selector you need to use is `$('input[name^="produtosBonificacao"]')` and also to add the sum , you need to convert the value of the input to an integer.

```
function subotal() {
    var sum = 0;
    $('input[name^="produtosBonificacao"]').each(function () {
        if($(this).attr('name').indexOf('.Preco') === -1) {
            return;
        }
        var price = parseInt($(this).val());
        sum += price;
    }); 
}
```

Comment: I specifically need the attribute Preco from the model produtosBonificacao.

Comment: @GustavoBorges check now

Comment: I got it.  Thx for your help. =)